# Sum of all real numbers in $]-60,60]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't solve this problem.
Find the sum of all real numbers in $]-60,60]$,
Is the answer zero or 60??
And of course why..

Comment: I hope you mean to say integers instead of real numbers?

Comment: If you want the integers, then they consist of $0,\pm n$ for $n=1,\dots,59$ and $60$, so the sum is 60.

Comment: I think that the sum of all real numbers, when there are uncountable positive and uncountable negative quantities, is undefined.

Comment: The obvious trick of pairing "each" real number with its negated counterpart to get a zero sum - leaving the single value of $+60$ unpaired - is only one possible way of an infinite variety of ways of calculating the sum, so the true value is "undefined".

Answer (score 5):

There are literally an uncountably infinite number of real numbers between $-60$ and $60$, so there's no way you can sum them all without having some rigorous definition of summing infinite quantities. One way we can do this is using calculus: If we sum $x$ from $-60$ to $60$ and give each $x$ a very small, but equal weight, we get the following integral:
$$\int_{-60}^{60} x\ dx=\frac{60^2}{2}-\frac{(-60)^2}{2}=0$$

However, this does not really count as the "sum of all real numbers between $-60$ and $60$." Since there are way too many numbers in that interval to sum that all, that sum is undefined. However, if you really need a numerical answer, even though it's really undefined, the answer I would choose is $0$.

Comment: +1 Yes, I think that is the best approach for the real case.

Answer (score 2):

If you meant integers, group them in pairs:
$$
60+\left(-59+59\right)+\left(-58+58\right)+\cdots+\left(-1+1\right)=?
$$

Comment: And if I mean real numbers??

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add infinitely many numbers. The following is NOT a sum.
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} = 2$$
It is the limit of partial sums. So the answer is that you cannot add up the numbers in $(-60,60]$. Another example,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$
The above is an alternating series that converges. However, by rearranging the terms, you can make it add up to anything you want, or you could make it diverge to $\infty$ or $-\infty$. The order in which things are added up makes a huge difference. Now, with all real numbers in $(-60, 60]$, there are uncountably many. So I don't see how you could even do a series-type "summation".

Comment: Is there an example of a reordering where you make the alternating harmonic series diverge to $+\infty$?

Comment: If you only take the even terms in the harmonic series, their partial sum diverges to $\infty$. One possible way of reordering to get $+\infty$ would be to take even terms until you get over 1. Then take the first odd term. Then take more even terms until you get over 2. Then the next odd term. Then more even terms until you get over 3. Repeating this gets a reordering that diverges to $+\infty$.

Comment: thanks I was fairly curious. It makes sense! It's unintuitive in one sense, but it makes sense in another.

Answer (score 1):

Another argument to see why adding infinitely many real numbers, of which infinitely many are positive and infinitely many are negative, is not well-defined, is the [Riemann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem). You can read the linked Wikipedia article for a worked example, but this theorem basically says that the **order** in which you add infinitely many numbers matters a lot! A classical example is the sum
$$
1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \ldots
$$
which converges to $\ln(2)$ when the numbers are added in the order above, but can be made to converge to **any** real number if the terms are rearranged. For example (copied from the Wikipedia article),
$$
1 - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{10} - \frac{1}{12} + \ldots
$$
converges to $\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)$, but the series consists of the same numbers!

I hope this convinces you why even simple generalisations of finite sums like series won't work for infinitely many real numbers of which infinitely many are positive and infinitely many are negative.

If all (but finitely many) are positive, then it is possible to add them rigorously.  As you might have guessed, the sum of all real numbers in $[0, 60]$ is $+\infty$.